# Reading geotifs from AWS S3 buckets using the R's aws.s3 package

Tags: r, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, raster

I am using an Rstudio Server Amazon Machine Image (AMI) from http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/. I have a number of large (~1.4GB) compressed TIFF images (LZW compression) in an Amazon S3 bucket. I've installed the aws.s3 and raster packages. When I attempt to move one of the tiffs into the AMI though using get_object() it imports as a vector rather than a geotiff (see below). Any suggestions about how to move it in as a raster would be appreciated.

```
> temp<-aws.s3::get_object(object="l***2.tif", bucket = 'b***b', key = 'A***Q', secret = 'k***p')

> raster(temp)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"raw"’

> is.vector(temp)
[1] TRUE

> length(temp)
[1] 1532610194

> temp[1:20]
 [1] 49 49 2a 00 08 00 00 00 13 00 00 01 03 00 01 00 00 00 0d c3
```

Comment: I assume you're using `raster::raster()`? The raw vector you're getting is the hex encoding of the file, where `raster` expects a file name, not the raw data from a file. The easy but inefficient workaround is to `save_object` to a local file and then import that with `raster`. I don't see an easy way around that, but if you dig into the `rgdal` package (which `raster` depends on for reading) you might be able to find something.

Comment: Thanks Gregor. Save_object() works well. Much appreciated. If I find something more efficient in rgdal, I'll post it here.

Comment: I looked enough to know it's not exported from `rgdal`, you'd need to hack some of the internals.

Comment: how installed raster on ami ?